# Transfer Apple Health data from old iPhone to new iPhone (without using iCloud)

Tags: health.app

For some reason I can't find an Apple official way to import old iPhone's Apple Health data to the new iPhone, that does not require using iCloud to backup.

There is an option to export, but strangely no option to import.

Comment: Are you trying to migrate **only** the health data, or is this part of a full migration?

Comment: only health data - not enough space to migrate all photos and other things etc

Comment: finally upgraded iCloud and still not seeing a way to migrate

Comment: I don't keep either Music or Photos in iCloud, they'a all on my Mac, so this might not work. If I've ever needed to temporarily use an older, smaller device I first un-sync music & photos, backup the now smaller version [encrypted, otherwise health & passwords don't get saved], then restore that to the smaller device.